# Have I to call delete in this destructors?

Tags: c++, class, destructor, delete-operator

Have I to call *delete* in this classes' destructors?

1. 2 pointers to Node:

   ```
   class Node {
   private:
       char Ch;
       int Key;
       Node* L;
       Node* R;
   public:
       Node() { L = NULL; R = NULL; }
       Node(char, int, Node*, Node*);
       ~Node();
   };
   ```
2. Vector of pointers to Node:

   ```
    class Example {
    private:
        vector<Node*> A;
    public:
        Node() {}
        Node(vector<Node*>);
        ~Node();
    };
   ```

In another class of my project I allocate Nodes through "new"!

Comment: It depends. One cannot tell from the code you have posted.

Comment: I don't see any calls to "new".

Comment: The member functions of your `Example` should be `Example`, not `Node`. ... and Stackoverflow isn't about having others do your work: what have you tried and what do you have problems with?

Comment: In another class of my project I allocate Nodes through "new"!

I'm not asking to solve my work, I wrote 2 examples of cases I don't understand.

Comment: As always, it depends on how the pointers were allocated and who is responsible for their life time.

Comment: So I have to call delete where I allocate the pointers, is this true?
When I allocate a vector of pointers, have I to call clear for the vector and delete for each pointer?

Comment: NODE is Node*, I edited, thank you juanchopanza!

Comment: @Maghio: "in another class...". That's a design problem right there. The pointers are `private`, so why is another class handling them? The `new` should be in the constructors of the class which owns the pointer, and `delete` in its destructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you allocate the nodes using `new` then you will eventually need to delete them, e.g. vector does not delete them for you, it only clears up the vector itself but not what the elements point to (since you have a vector of pointers). As you can tell the ownership of a node can be a bit tricky to establish in your classes - what class should delete? That is why using smart pointers like `shared_ptr<>` and `unique_ptr<>` make your life much easier.

e.g.

```
std::shared_ptr<Node> L;
std::shared_ptr<Node> R;
```

and

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> A;
```

then you do not need to worry about deleting

Comment: Thank you.

I have another question about it.

If I have a binary tree and i want to use simple pointers, in my class Node i have to call delete in the destructor for the left and right childs wich are pointers to Node. In this way, when the destructor is called, the root, wich isn't a child but is a pointer to Node, will be not deleted, is it true? Have I to call another delete also for the root?

Comment: IMHO: This feels like a recursive problem so instead of deleting inside of Node have a cleanup function that recursively goes through the tree starting deletion at the leaves. If you delete inside of Node you must make each node aware of where they are in the tree e.g. am I root? and if you in the future then want to say reorganize the tree it will be more cumbersome to move nodes.